# usage of alternative question

Tags: questions

Is it correct to say:
" Is the church at the end of the street catholic or it isn't? " If it is not then, please, explain why it is not and give the correct usage of alt. question in this example.

Comment: No, it is not grammatical. But to get more detailed answers to this A, especially the second part focused on more natural formulations, it should be asked on our sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: "Is the church at the end of the street a Catholic church?" sounds ok.

Comment: It's not correct because both clauses should be questions in form. The word order in the first clause is _Is the church ...?_, so it should be _or isn't it?_ in the second.

Answer (score 0):

We generally use a positive question and "or" followed by the opposite negative question in order to express impatience, anger or exasperation, e.g. at lack of clarity, or strong need to know, for example "Are you coming or aren't you?" (implication: I want to know now whether you are coming, and you should already have made this clear). "Is that coin gold, or isn't it?" (It is not clear whether the coin is made of gold, and I strongly wish to know). This form is not used for routine questions if no anger or urgency is being suggested. The full form of the negative question is [verb to be] [pronoun] not - is it not? Are they not? Will he not?, etc. The abbreviated form uses the shortened form of negative 'to be' forms - isn't he? Won't you? Didn't I?

Thus:  "Did I tell you to clean your room, or did I not/didn't I?".

You would ask this question: "Is the church at the end of the street Catholic or is it not/isn't it?" to express frustration at not knowing the answer, and at not having been given the information already. It is hard to think of a situation in which this particular question would be asked in this way, (I need to confess right now!) and I imagine it is simply an example made up to illustrate the information being sought.

[Negative questions](https://www.englishgrammar.org/negative-questions/)